# Architecture Components: How does the ViewModelProvider know which constructor to call?

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

I've been reading about the new Architecture Components that were introduced to Android and I cannot figure out how this works:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(Activity).get(Class)
```

Initially I thought that it calls the default constructor and returns a ViewModel object that you then instantiate with eg. an init() method as per

```
public class UserProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private String userId;
    private User user;

    public void init(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Snippet taken from the guide: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

However, later on in the guide there is this snippet:

```
public class UserProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<User> user;
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Inject // UserRepository parameter is provided by Dagger 2
    public UserProfileViewModel(UserRepository userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public void init(String userId) {
        if (this.user != null) {
            // ViewModel is created per Fragment so
            // we know the userId won't change
            return;
        }
        user = userRepo.getUser(userId);
    }
```

So how does the ViewModelProvider know to call the provided constructor? Or it sees that there is only 1 constructor and calls that? For example if there were 2 constructors what would happen?

I tried digging through the code and what I found was:

```
@Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (AndroidViewModel.class.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)) {
                //noinspection TryWithIdenticalCatches
                try {
                    return modelClass.getConstructor(Application.class).newInstance(mApplication);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
                } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
                }
            }
            return super.create(modelClass);
        }
```

Inside of the `DefaultFactory` class inside `ViewModelProviders.java`. However, this confused me even further. How does `getConstructor(Application.class)` even work when `ViewModel` objects do not have a constructor taking an Application as an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the snippet there is a condition that checks if *modelClass* is of type `AndroidViewModel` (inherits `ViewModel`) which constructor takes `Application` parameter. This is more like exclusive case that spares the `Factory` of looking up for constructor matching specific parameters. 
This provider looks up for constructor matching provider arguments when creating it:

```
public class ViewModelParameterizedProvider {

    private AtomicBoolean set = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private ViewModelStore viewModelStore = null;


    static ViewModelParameterizedProvider getProvider() {
        return new ViewModelParameterizedProvider();
    }

    @MainThread
    public static ViewModelProvider ofSupportFragment(Fragment fragment, Object... params) {
        return getProvider().of(fragment).with(params);
    }

    @MainThread
    public static ViewModelProvider ofActivity(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, Object... params) {
        return getProvider().of(fragmentActivity).with(params);
    }

    @MainThread
    public static ViewModelProvider ofFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment, Object... params) {
        return getProvider().of(fragment).with(params);
    }

    private ViewModelParameterizedProvider of(Fragment fragment) {
        checkForPreviousTargetsAndSet();
        viewModelStore = ViewModelStores.of(fragment);
        return this;
    }

    private ViewModelParameterizedProvider of(android.app.Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentActivity fragAct = (FragmentActivity) fragment.getActivity();
        return of(fragAct);
    }

    private ViewModelParameterizedProvider of(FragmentActivity activity) {
        checkForPreviousTargetsAndSet();
        viewModelStore = ViewModelStores.of(activity);
        return this;
    }


    private ViewModelProvider with(Object... constructorParams) {
        return new ViewModelProvider(viewModelStore, parametrizedFactory(constructorParams));
    }


    private void checkForPreviousTargetsAndSet() {
        if (set.get()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewModelStore already has been set. Create new instance.");
        }
        set.set(true);
    }

    private ViewModelProvider.Factory parametrizedFactory(Object... constructorParams) {
        return new ParametrizedFactory(constructorParams);
    }


    private final class ParametrizedFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        private final Object[] mConstructorParams;

        ParametrizedFactory(Object... constructorParams) {
            mConstructorParams = constructorParams;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            if (modelClass == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Target ViewModel class can not be null")
            }
            Log.w("ParametrizedFactory", "Don't use callbacks or Context parameters in order to avoid leaks!!")
            try {
                if (mConstructorParams == null || mConstructorParams.length == 0) {
                    return modelClass.newInstance();
                } else {
                    Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[mConstructorParams.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < mConstructorParams.length; i++) {
                        classes[i] = mConstructorParams[i].getClass();
                    }
                    return modelClass.getConstructor(classes).newInstance(mConstructorParams);
                }
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [kotlin version](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/e33ba440cce4dda1a99e35b499e3f6a2).
Here is [more read on the subject](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/parameterized-viewmodelprovider-s-9148207ec048)